# How to get DNS records of App Engine after the custom domain has been set up?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a question about Google App Engine.

If a custom domain has been added, App Engine will prompt the DNS record in the last setup step.
[image]

I wonder where to get the DNS records when the custom domain has been already set up?

Comment: You can easily get them from the same place that you set them.  E.g., I use Google domains.

Comment: I have provided an answer below.Hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

According to this documentation on [Updating DNS records at your domain registrar](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#dns_update)

> You can retrieve DNS records any time on the Custom Domains tab of the App Engine Settings page.
>
> In the Google Cloud console, go to the Custom Domains tab of the App Engine Settings page. The page lists DNS records for all of the domains you have mapped to your app.
>
> Sign in to your domain registrar web site and update your DNS records with the records